# acomodar tablas en dos columnas en fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

he estado trabajando en fpdf realizando tablas con informacion extraida de mysql,las tablas se van generando a partir de informacion de la BD, el problema es que mis tablas se acomodan todas hacia abajo y lo que requiero es acomodar mis tablas en dos columnas dentro de cada pagina, de modo que quepan 4 tablas dentro de la hoja, actualmente asi me imprime las tablas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he tratando de implementar usar columnas multiples en fpdf pero como tengo codigo con sql me rechaza la instrucción Class Pdf extends FPDF

```
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->Addpage('L','Letter');
$pdf->Ln();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado) ) {
for ($tarima=$tarimaini;  $tarima <=$tarimafin ; $tarima++) {


$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',13);
//$pdf->Rect(6,6,133,90,'D');
$pdf->Cell(28,10,'PRODUCTO','TRLB',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(97,10,$fila['producto'],1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',13);
$pdf->Cell(28,10,'LOTE',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(97,10,$fila['lote'],1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(28,10,'CANTIDAD',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(97,10,$fila['cantidad'],1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(28,10,'FECHA',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(37,10,$fila['fecha'],1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'TARIMA',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$tarima,1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(28,10,'IDH',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(37,10,$fila['codigo'],1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'TURNO',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$fila['descturno'],1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',7);
$pdf->Cell(65,4,'CALIDAD',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,4,'PRODUCCION',1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',5);
$pdf->Cell(65,27,'Vo.Bo.CC',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(60,27,'Vo.Bo. PROD.',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Ln(7);

   }
}


$pdf->Output();
mysql_close();
```

hasta aqui esta la parte donde genero mi tabla en fpdf y concateno mis campos de sql

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
include("conexion.php");

$tarimaini = $_POST['tarimaini'];
$tarimafin = $_POST['tarimafin'];

$solicitud ="SELECT productos.codigo,productos.producto,productos.cantidad, papeleta.lote,papeleta.fecha,papeleta.tarimaini,papeleta.tarimafin,turnopersonal.descturno FROM `papeleta` 
LEFT JOIN productos ON papeleta.codigo=productos.codigo 
LEFT JOIN turnopersonal ON papeleta.turno=turnopersonal.turno ORDER BY codigo_pap desc limit 1 ";  
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$solicitud);
    $i=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
```

y esto lo tengo en la parte de arriba de mi script, es la consulta en mysql, si hay algo mas que deseen que muestre de mi codigo no tengo problema, gracias

Comment: Hola. De forma en poderte ayudar a acomodar el HTML de manera correcta, por favor considera agregar el código HTML que estás generando previo a ejecutar FPDF

Comment: @FernandoTorres claro amigo, ya edite la pregunta, si algo me falta por mostrar estoy a sus ordenes

Comment: Buenos Dias @CarlosSosa  te voy a colocar una respuesta en la manera que yo acomodo dos "tablas" en posición horizontal.

Comment: Yo creo que la diferencia clave entre la respuesta que te dan y tu código es el `$this->SetXY(10,42);`. Tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema de márgenes del documento

Comment: @Alfabravo disculpa mi ignorancia, entonces tendria que cambiar mi codigo de $pdf-> a $this-> o estoy interpretando mal?

Comment: A ver. Mira que en la respuesta **crean una clase** que extiende FPDF y le pone un montón de cosas adicionales a los headers de las páginas; seguramente cada página del PDF del amigo Cesarin sale con esa tabla. Tú sólo estás instanciando la clase FPDF (en `$pdf`) y ya usas los métodos y tal. Puedes probar usando tu código y añadiendo algunas instrucciones como setXY y probar. Es importante que revises bien TODO el código en la respuesta y entiendas qué pasa :)

Comment: @Alfabravo efectivamente esta instrucción $this->SetXY(xx,yy) condiciona un punto de origen para crear una celda  o una multicelda en mi caso primero inicio una multicelda con una posición o coordenada, y dentro de esa multilcelda puedes agrupar mas multiceldas o celdas según requieras basandote en el mismo punto indicado como inicio.  al menos a mi me ha funcionado así.

Comment: Muy buena observación, que bueno que estas revisando el código, y efectivamente estos recuadros que muestro son una cabecera que tiene que salir en cada pagina impresa,  pero si el compañero @Carlos Sosa solo requiere imprimir 4 tablas por hoja, es solo cuestión de que adapte el código sacándolo del header y le debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: @CarlosSosa puedes probar sin el "$this->"   asignando directamente en el $pdf->SETXY(xx,yy) te debería funcionar, yo base mi pdf en parte en la documentación del sitio oficial de FPDF http://www.fpdf.org/  , disponible en español, puedes consultar los ejemplos, yo estoy utilizando dos archivos

Comment: @Cesarin disculpa amigo, que funcion tiene la instruccion multicell  en tu codigo, ya que yo lo he metido a mi codigo y en si se sobrepone a la primeras papeletas de cada hoja, tendria que poner toda mi tabla con un multicell o solo es sobreponerla a las que tengo para que me haga las demas instrucciones?

Comment: @CarlosSosa , precisamente ayer despues de ver la imagen de tu trabajo, me quede pensando en que posiblemente tendrias alguna duda, el primer multicell que estoy utilizando yo lo uso como un marco,  y luego dentro de el, voy colocando las celdas u otras multiceldas para poder construir y se vea la imagen como la aprecias.

Comment: @Cesarin de hecho olvide comentar que las papeletas se replican conforme a la cantidad que le pido dentro de un formulario anterior, por ello jalo los datos de $tarimaini y $tarimafin para establecer un rango de impresion, de hecho tengo mas papeletas abajo de la imagen pero usando tu codigo  "setXY($posicionMulticelda...)" me encima en un solo lugar todas papeletas no se si tendria que hacerle un cambio ahi

Comment: @CarlosSosa  Al menos tendrías que imprimir una papeleta, y como máximo 4 papeletas por hoja,  podría ser el caso que sean solo 2 o solo 3 ?..  Por que entonces se tendría que hacer "dinámico" el proceso de mostrar las tablas con coordenadas

Comment: @Cesarin pues minimo seria imprimir una papeleta y maximo 4 por cada hoja, entonces supongo que si seria hacerlo dinamico, acabo de leer tambien tu explicacion abajo gracias, estoy tratando de entender lo mas rapido posible porque llevo muy poco usando fpdf y no quiero colmarles la paciencia con tanta pregunta,de hecho esta estructura no la habia encontrado en ningun lado en internet

Comment: @CarlosSosa, no te preocupes, es mejor preguntar , y que alguien tenga la disposición de ayudar,  que es lo que realmente importa, compartir un poco de lo que se hace.  De hecho a much@s se les complica un buen, el poder crear los pdfs , con cualquiera de las herramientas que hay para ello,  es solo tener paciencia y dedicarle un tiempo

Comment: Revisa este portal, es la documentacion "oficial" de FPDF   http://www.fpdf.org/  ahi me base para hacer parte de mi código, lo demás es cosecha de muchas partes,  de hecho lo hago así por que se me complica mucho hacerlo como tu lo hiciste de celda por celda.  La Multicelda me ayuda mucho por que permite colocar dentro mas multiceldas y celdas dentro de estas,  igual se puede solo tener una multicelda, y jugar con las celdas dentro de esta, pero a mi se me facilita mas así como te lo estoy exponiendo.

Comment: Y buscándole mucho, hay mucho código, que te quedarías cuadrado de lo que hacen, pero la verdad se me hace ya muy complejo para andar copiando código que no le entiendo. Dice un compañero, hazlo fácil, juega fácil, que funcione bien, pero sin complicarlo demasiado. checa los tutoriales del sitio oficial de FPDF hay bastante información que te puede ayudar, ya que tiene una sección de códigos de terceros.  Checa este titulo ahi "Table with MultiCells"  creo que te seria bastante util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carlos te explico a groso modo que hago:

```
$this->MultiCell(137,25,'',1); esta multicelda tiene cuartro parametros o valores:
en el phpStorm que yo utilizo como IDE, te pone las referencias de esta manera
$this->MultiCell(w:137,h:25,txt:'',b:1);
w:137 quiere decir que la multicelda tendrá un ancho de 137 casi la mitad de la hoja en horizontal 
h:25 indica que tendrá una altura de 25 aquí puedes acomodar 5 celdas o multiceldas con altura de 5 suficiente para texto, en caso que el texto sea mas "alto" reduces el tamaño del texto.
txt: 'texto'.
b:1  borde, en este caso lo pinta en la pantalla.
```

Bajo este esquema entonces mi primer multicelda es un recuadro que bordea los demás elementos, por eso también la idea de poner color y el borde, así formas el marco:

```html
$this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetDrawColor(224,235,255);
        $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY);
        $this->MultiCell(137,25,'',1);
```

Si te fijas en la imagen, tengo una cabecera rellena y con texto :

```
$this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'DATOS DE LA DEPENDENCIA', 1,1,'C',$fill);// Esto crea la cabecera con el texto DATOS DE LA DEPENDENCIA.
```

Después agrego otra multicelda, y una celda más donde coloco mi primer elemento que requiero mostrar, en este caso el titulo o etiqueta del dato a mostrar 'DEPENDENCIA':

```
$this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+5);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'DEPENDENCIA:', 1,1,'L');
```

//si te fijas añadí 5 para que tenga esta altura y se pueda colocar la celda que también tiene una altura de 5.
Para agregar lo que traigo de la consulta mysql como un valor lo coloco en otra multicelda, donde le indico que tendrá que estar espaciada +35 y con altura igual de 5
para colocar dentro lo que traigo de la consulta y esto quedaría así:

```
$this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX+35,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+5);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombreInstitutoRH),0,1,'L',0); <<-- Valor de la consulta.
```

Esto hace que el texto que trae la variable de la consulta en mysql, se imprima 35 espacios o puntos después de la palabra DEPENDENCIA.

De esta manera se van formando los "cuadritos" o "celdas" de la tabla.

Te recomendaría que, del código que te expuse , copiarlo en otro archivo para recrearlo solo quitarle los $this y sustituye por $pdf en base a tu estructura del código,  ponle los bordes a todas las celdas y multiceldas para que veas como se comporta, modifica los números y veras como se modifica la estructura.

Si es un tanto complicado al principio, pero una vez que entiendas como posicionar las multiceldas y las celdas en base a puntos o coordenadas, te sera mucho mas sencillo construir tu pagina de 4 tablas.

Imaginate que estas jugando con un lego...

Recuerda que si utilizaste esto:  `$PDF->MultiCell(137,25,'',1);`  y te sobre escribe sobre las celdas que ya tienes, entonces hace falta verificar la altura de tus celdas y la cantidad de estas a lo alto y ancho, entonces el 25 podría ser, 35, 50, 70, según el alto de tus celdas y a lo ancho 137 también podría variar de acuerdo al tamaño del texto, la cantidad de datos a mostrar, etc.. , en cada una de las celdas.

Saludos

Comment: @CarlosSosa checa este script  podria serte util:  http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Te complemento la razon del por que el codigo esta construido de esta manera, yo manejo dos archivos, uno para llamar a dos "metodos" de construir el pdf, no en salida por descarga de archivo y el otro por impresion en la pantalla, de esta manera tengo el archivo base que se encarga de crear la peticion del pdf:

```html
switch ($botonPresionado){


        case 'DescargarResguardo':

            $pdf = new PDF('L');  // creas el nuevo pdf
            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(1, 10); // Corta la pagina en la posicion indicada
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 5);
            $pdf->Header();   // este es solo en caso que requieras que aparezca en todas las hojas como cabecera, si no ocupas este header, tienes que sacar de ahí el código que te genera las dos tablas
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 5);
            // Títulos de las columnas
            $header = array('No.', 'MUNICIPIO', 'NUMERO_ACTIVO', 'SUBNUMERO', 'DESCRIPCIÓN DEL BIEN', 'MATERIAL', 'COLOR', 'MARCA', 'MODELO', 'SERIE', 'ESTADO DEL BIEN');  // cabecera de la tabla de información
            // Carga de la tabla
            $pdf->ActivosTable($header); Aqui carga la tabla con su cabecera
            $pdf->datos_usuarios(); // carga otros datos relacionados al formato
            // Aquí hago una instancia para accesar a Mysql
            // Aquí un for para obtener los datos de salida del nombre   del archivo
            
            $pdf->Output('RESGUARDO INDIVIDUAL-'.$Numero_Empleado.'-'.$nombre_EmpleadoRH .'-'. date('d-m-Y') .'.pdf', 'D');
            break;

        case 'ImprimirResguardo':
```

Esta es la manera en que yo coloco dos cuadros de información en horizontal y alineados en base a  posiciones dentro de la pagina a imprimir(coordenadas si lo quieres ver así)

```
    class PDF extends FPDF {

        function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            $this->Image('imagenes/logos/FondoResguardo2.jpg',0,0,300,0);
            // Arial bold 15
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',6);

            // Aquí hago mis instancias para poder cargar los datos//
            

            for($rh=0; $rh< $totalResultadoListaRecursoshumanos; $rh++){
               //Aquí hago un recorrido de la consulta para asignar los valores a cada variable

            }  // esto de arriba de las instancias y el recorrido a lo mejor no es necesario para ti
            $this->SetFont('','B');
            $fill = True;
            $this->SetXY(10,42);//Esquina del inicio del margen de la cabecera dependencia // 
            
            $posicion_MulticeldaDX= $this->GetX();//Aquí inicializo donde va a comenzar el primer recuadro en la posición X
            $posicion_MulticeldaDY= $this->GetY();//Aquí inicializo donde va a comenzar el primer recuadro en la posición Y
            //Estas lineas comentadas las ocupo para verificar la posición, imprime la posición de cada eje//
            //$this->Cell(50,5,utf8_decode('Posicion X'  ." " .$posicion_MulticeldaDX),1,0,'C');
            //$this->Cell(50,5,utf8_decode('Posicion Y'  ." " .$posicion_MulticeldaDY),1,0,'C');
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//**************************************************************************//
          // Estas lineas son para asignar relleno, color del texto y color de lineas de contorno si mal no recuerdo //
            $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255); 
            $this->SetTextColor(0); 
            $this->SetDrawColor(224,235,255);  

//*************************************************************************//
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY); //Aquí le indicas la posición de la esquina superior izquierda para el primer multicell que envuelve toda la tabla o recuadro
            $this->MultiCell(137,25,'',1);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY); // Esto posiciona cada etiqueta en base a la posición de la esquina 
            $this->Cell(137,5,'DATOS DE LA DEPENDENCIA', 1,1,'C',$fill);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+5);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'DEPENDENCIA:', 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX+35,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+5);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombreInstitutoRH),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+10);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'UR:', 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX+35,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+10);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombreUnidadResponsableRH) ,0,1,'L',0);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+15);
            $this->Cell(137,5,utf8_decode('DIRECCIÓN GENERAL:'), 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX+35,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+15);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode('DIRECCIÓN DE ADMINISTRACION Y FINANZAS' ),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+20);
            $this->Cell(137,5,utf8_decode('DIRECCIÓN DE AREA:'), 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaDX+35,$posicion_MulticeldaDY+20);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombreUnidadRH),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->Ln();  // Termina seccion de multicelda de datos de dependencia
            $this->SetFont('','B');
            $fill = True;
            $this->SetXY(153,42); // Esquina del unicio de la cabecera del usuario//
            $posicion_MulticeldaUX= $this->GetX();
            $posicion_MulticeldaUY= $this->GetY();
            $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
            $this->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->SetDrawColor(224,235,255);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX,$posicion_MulticeldaUY);
            $this->MultiCell(137,25,'',1);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX,$posicion_MulticeldaUY);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'DATOS DEL USUARIO', 1,1,'C',$fill);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+5);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'NUMERO DE EMPLEADO:', 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX+40,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+5);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($numero_EmpleadoRH),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+10);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'NOMBRE DE EMPLEADO:', 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX+40,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+10);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombre_EmpleadoRH),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+15);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'NIVEL TABULAR:', 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX+40,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+15);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nivel_TabularRH),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+20);
            $this->Cell(137,5,'CATEGORIA O PUESTO:', 0,1,'L');
            $this->SetXY($posicion_MulticeldaUX+40,$posicion_MulticeldaUY+20);
            $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($puestoNominalRH),0,1,'L',0);
            $this->Ln();
            //$this->Cell(185,5,'', 0,1,'L');
            $posicion_CierreCeldaCabeceraX = $this->GetX();
            $posicion_CierreCeldaCabeceraY = $this->GetY();
            //$this->Cell(50, 5, utf8_decode('Posicion X' . " " . $posicion_CierreCeldaCabeceraX), 1, 0, 'C');
            //$this->Cell(50, 5, utf8_decode('Posicion Y' . " " . $posicion_CierreCeldaCabeceraY), 1, 0, 'C');
        }
```

De esta manera se pueden colocar dos recuadros o tablas ajustados de manera horizontal

Y esta es la vista que obtienes[image: Vista de la salida del PDF]

Puedes adaptar el este código a tu necesidad, no requieres del $this-> si estas trabajando en un mismo archivo para crear el pdf.  Basta con que utilices el $pdf->SetXY(10,42);//Esquina del inicio del margen de la primer tabla, esto te asigna el primer punto de origen, ahora también tienes que jugar con los números ya que esta es la posición que yo tengo en base a un par de logos y una cabecera de texto que me consumen 42 espacios desde el inicio de la pagina.  A lo mejor tu requieres que sea $pdf->SetXY(5,5); o $pdf->SetXY(10,10);.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Esto depende del tamaño de la página (A4, Carta, Oficio, etc.)? Es que no es muy diferente a lo que hace el OP. ¿Por qué crees que funciona?

Comment: @Alfabravo  Si hay una sutil diferencia, y es que se le asigna a cada tabla un punto de origen en donde sera mostrada en la pagina, en este caso es solo para ser mostrado en una pagina tamaño carta, para A4, Oficio u otra medida tendría que adaptarse a lo alto y ancho de la pagina.